# How to override Select.php block file in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, overrides

How to override vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php file

I have followed below steps, but not working
Step1: Created di.xml

```
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
```

Step2: created

```
app/code/Vendor/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{


    public function getValuesHtml()
    {  


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things.

1. Create di.xml file at following place.

   app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

   with code

"

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"
type="Vendor\Extension\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"/>
```

"

2. Create Block file at following location.

   app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

   use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select as TypeSelect;

   class Select extends TypeSelect
   {
      public function getValuesHtml()
       {
       // Do your custom code here
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have followed above steps but still not working

Comment: the above steps is not working.

Comment: I already do this things in my one extension. Please verify path specify in di.xml. In your code you forgot to mension Extension name.

Comment: Hi Dhiren , thanks for quick reply and have u overrided same file ?

Comment: yes, I overide same file in my custom extension. So I posted answer here.

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle found the answer. 
This is what I did to override block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

**File - [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
    <plugin name="[Vendor]_[Module]_select" sortOrder="10"
            type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"/>
</type>
```

**File - [Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions
{

 public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)
 {
    $_option = $subject->getOption();
    $configValue = $subject->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
    $store = $subject->getProduct()->getStore();

    $subject->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
    // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
    ) {
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';

        $extraParams = '';
        $select = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
            ]
        );
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            // Code changes start
            if($_option->getIsSize()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Size'));
            }
            else if($_option->getIsCut()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Cut'));
            }
            else{
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select an Option'));
            }
            // Code changes end
        } else {
            $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . '][]');
            $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
        }
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ],
                false
            );
            $select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                ['price' => $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
            );
        }
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
            $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
        }
        if (!$subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
        }
        $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
        $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

        if ($configValue) {
            $select->setValue($configValue);
        }

        return $select->getHtml();
    }

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
    ) {
        $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
        $arraySign = '';
        switch ($_option->getType()) {
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                $type = 'radio';
                $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                    $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                        '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '" class="' .
                        $class .
                        ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        ']"' .
                        ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                        ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                        ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '"><span>' .
                        __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                }
                break;
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                $type = 'checkbox';
                $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                $arraySign = '[]';
                break;
        }
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $count++;

            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ]
            );

            $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
            if ($arraySign) {
                $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
            } else {
                $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
            }

            $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
            if ($arraySign) {
                $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
            }

            $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                $require .
                '">' .
                '<input type="' .
                $type .
                '" class="' .
                $class .
                ' ' .
                $require .
                ' product-custom-option"' .
                ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                ' name="options[' .
                $_option->getId() .
                ']' .
                $arraySign .
                '" id="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '" value="' .
                $htmlValue .
                '" ' .
                $checked .
                ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                ' price="' .
                $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                '" />' .
                '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '"><span>' .
                $_value->getTitle() .
                '</span> ' .
                $priceStr .
                '</label>';
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';
        }
        $selectHtml .= '</div>';

        return $selectHtml;
    }
 }
}
```

Important things to note here - 
After copying \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php to [Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php, you must do following.

1. Change the namespace to `[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;`
2. Replace `public function getValuesHtml()` to `public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)`
3. Replace `$this` to `$subject`

Hope this helps.